# Modifying folder permissions

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Need a little help. The script is not changing the permissions at all.

I want to make the name of the folder be the owner of the folder with full rights.

```
$foldernames = (Get-ChildItem \\knesmbmdc001\profiles).Name
$user = "$foldernames"
$usercount = 0
foreach($name in $foldernames)
{
If ($usercount -le 5)
{
    Try
    {

        $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user,"FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
        $acl = get-acl $name
        $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
        Set-acl $name $acl
    }
    catch
    {
    Add-Content C:\user_done.txt $name
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problems with your script:

- The first argument passed to `New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` should be `$name`, not `$user`.
- Your `Add-Content` call to write to a log file should not be in the `catch` clause, as it will then only log if the ACL operation did *not* succeed.
- By having no other statements in your `catch` clause, exceptions are effectively *ignored*.
- You're passing mere folder *names* to cmdlets that expect *paths* (`Get-Acl`, `Set-Acl`), which only works if the current location happens to be the folder's parent location.

Here's a reformulation of your script that should work as intended:

```powershell
$dir = '\\knesmbmdc001\profiles'
$logFile = 'C:\user_done.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Directory $dir | % {
    $user = $_.Name
    $acl = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $user, FullControl, "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", None, Allow
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl -LiteralPath $_ -AclObject $acl
    Add-Content $logFile $user
 }
```

Note, however, that while this **will give *full control*** to the target user, it **does not make them the *owner*** of the folder.

To actually **change ownership**, try the following (replace the `$rule=...` and `$acl.AddAccessRule...` commands):

```
$userIdentity = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount $user
$acl.SetOwner($userIdentity)
```

This worked for me with a local user account while running with elevated privileges, but YMMV.

Comment: I have the robocopy running now, if the permissions are still not right I will start testing your script. Thanks for your help.

I just seen the last statement. What do I need to add to make them the owner?

Comment: Get-Acl : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'kostxing.im'.
At \\kiewitplaza\vdi\appsense_profiles\Take_ownership_profile.ps1:6 char:12
+     $acl = Get-Acl $user $_
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Acl], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At \\kiewitplaza\vdi\appsense_profiles\Take_ownership_profile.ps1:9 char:5
+     $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: @user770022: Re `Get-Acl` error: looks like you're passing _2_ parameters, `$user` and `$_`, which may be the problem; my code only passes `$_` - the folder (path) at hand -  via `-LiteralPath`.

Comment: Re `null-vallued expression` error: This error is a consequence of the `Get-Acl` error: variable `$acl` hasn't been set, is therefore `$null`, and any attempt to call a method on `$null` results in that error. The `Get-Acl` error was a _non-terminating_ error, unlike the `null-value` one, which is why the code kept going after the former. To prevent that you can set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, for instance.