# Get the current owner and permissions of a registry key using SetACL

Tags: cmd, command-line, windows-10, registry

Using SetACL from Helge Klein via a batch file, I want to change the owner and permissions of a registry key just to change its values, then later bring it back to its original owner and permissions, but to do that I need to know the correct syntax to get the current owner and permissions of a registry key.

This is my current situation:

The problem:

1. Get the current owner
2. Get the current Administrator permissions

What I've done and it works:

3. Change owner to Administrators (not recursively)
4. Change Administrator permissions to full (not recursively)
5. Edit registry values under the key

The consequence of solving the problem:

6. Restore Administrator permissions with those previously obtained. (not recursively)
7. Restore owner with the one previously obtained. (not recursively)

The example key is the following:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\Powershell
```

and thanks to this topic: https://superuser.com/questions/712392
I have obtained this partial code:

```
REM Pseudo code:
owner = $(SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\Powershell" -ot reg -actn ?)
adminPerms = $(SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\Powershell" -ot reg -actn ?)

REM Known code:
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\Powershell" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr n:Administrators
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\Powershell" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:Administrators;p:full"
REG IMPORT "System config.reg"

REM Hypothetical code:
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\Powershell" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr n:%owner%
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shell\Powershell" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:Administrators;p:%adminPerms%"
```

What is the syntax to use to get the current owner and permissions (pseudo code section)?

Comment: To begin with, you should not be touching that registry key. The key you should be modifying is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\PowerShell`.

Comment: Thank you for this detail.
I was already aware that `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a shortcut for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes` but the permissions issue doesn't change and I would like a solution to the question posed in this topic.

Comment: What I'm telling you is the you should not change the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key, you should change the key which propagates it. That means nobody should provide an anwswer which modifies the key you've used in the question you've posed, they should provide one which modifies HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes instead.

Comment: I know it. But is there anyone who can provide me with a solution using SetACL? I decided to use SetACL, from Helge Klein.

Comment: This site does not provide a free project/task management service, nor does it write code for you, or tell you exactly what and how to write it yourself. This site helps you to fix a properly explained and debugged specific issue with the code that you've written and submitted to perform the task that you've laid out, and which fails to do so. Your question doesn't include any code, or debugging information, and therefore does not currently fulfil the guidelines for an on topic question. Please take some time to read through the linked pages within [ask], to better understand those guidelines.

Comment: This site helps in the difficulties of developers. I know how to set the owner and permissions using SetACL but not how to restore the original ones.

Comment: How about you use the [edit] facility, and completely overhaul your question, to include that code, show us the complete set of permissions before you run it, and the complete set of permissions after you run it, then include the code you've also written to revert to the previous settings, and tell us what about that code is not working. A professional will write code for you to a specific task or set of requirements, for a fee. Just offering points, is not the same as paying somebody for a professional service, so please do not expect that type of service.

Comment: Comments from other people are also welcome to help me investigate or correct the question.

Comment: Mario, you have stated that you have decided to use a very specific command utility to perform this task, i.e. `SetACL`, yet you've shown absolutely no indication that you've even read its help/man pages, or tried anything at all yourself. If we do not know what you have, or have not done, we would essentially be asking you to do something you may have already tried, which would be wasted effort, or guessing. This is a technical site, so we should not be making guesses, we should be helping you based upon facts. You've provided no code which means we have no facts upon which to base an answer.

Comment: This is true. I'm making the change.

Comment: To be clear, as you've still not provided us with any code, and as you've specifically told us that you've obtained the original owner and permission information, is your question simply how to restore those permissions and owner. If so how did you 'obtain'/backup the initial settings. If you did not really back them up, is your question really how do I backup and restore the owner and permissions of a registry subkey? If that is indeed your question, then it is simply looking for research information, and not actually seeking an answer to an on topic programming issue.

Comment: Before commenting further, it was enough to wait for my change. It took me a while.

Comment: Your pseudo code is not using [[tag:cmd]] syntax, despite you having used that tag. Which command line interface are you using, cmd.exe, powershell.exe, or some other? Also, I expected that the modification you made one minute and ten seconds before your comment, was relating to that comment, I had no way of knowing otherwise!

Comment: Mario, all I'm trying to do is get you to make all of the required changes to your question in order that it attract quality and focused answers to an on topic question. Currently the only reason you'll get those answers seems to be the points bribe. Take a look at what your question looked like when you initially offered it, and how it is now, then tell me that the changes you've made, at my request have not improved your chances of receiving a solution much greater. I'm sorry that you disagree with my assessment, but the way I see it, for something important, I'd show more effort/try harder.

Comment: I corrected it along the way, that's what comments are for. I had to first define what I had in mind.

Comment: Is using PowerShell (possibly via a CLI call from `cmd.exe`) an option? You could then use `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35237079/45375) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Identities:

```
 //Get Owner
 $acl = Get-Acl HKCU:\Identities
 $GetOwner = $acl.Owner
 echo $GetOwner 

 //Get Permissions
 $aclPermissions = Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control | Format-List
```